# Qual a melhor forma de consultar base SQL Server utilizando como entrada uma lista?

Tags: java, sql-server, desempenho

Estou com uma dúvida quanto à melhor forma de abordar o seguinte problema:
Preciso consultar registros em uma tabela SQL Server utilizando uma lista de números de série. Conheço o comando IN, porém ele não atende, por se limitar a receber o máximo de 2100 dados como parâmetro e minha lista possui muito mais do que isso.

Gostaria de saber se é melhor:

- subdividir a minha lista antes da chamada e fazer várias consultas
- passar a lista somente uma vez e consultar registro a registro(utilizando um for no java para percorrer a lista)

Qual seria a forma com melhor desempenho? Irei realizar meus testes aqui em ambas as opções, porém imagino que alguém tenha uma experiência nisso e que possa me prevenir de cometer um equívoco.

Comment: Você realmente precisa de 2000 parâmetros?

Comment: Sim, pois dependerá dos filtros fornecidos na tela de requisição, que podem variar muito.

Comment: Mas haverá mais de duas mil opções na tela de requisição? Se com essa tela de requisição vc quer dizer uma consulta, não tem muita lógica colocar tantos parametros para escolha... Ao meu ponto de vista, é lógico.

Comment: Não, serão algumas combos, que pesquisarão esses registros em outra base de dados, que populam a minha lista, então depende do valor passado nas combos. Desculpe se ficou confuso antes, agora consegui esclarecer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos analisar algumas possibilidades, incluindo as que você citou.

## Leitura em Blocos

Dividir os items em blocos de igual tamanho e executar consultas usando o *IN* até ler todos os itens.

- **Vantagem:** lê somente os dados necessários.
- **Desvantagem**: precisa de várias consultas (qtd. itens / tamanho do bloco)
- **Conclusão**: é a melhor solução genérica quando não se tem ideia da quantidade de itens a serem pesquisados e da quantidade total de dados existentes na tabela.

## Leitura Individual

Ler registro a registro.

- **Vantagem:** não vejo nenhuma.
- **Desvantagem**: aumenta muito o número de consultas e o *overhead* de processamento. Embora possa parecer que a quantidade de dados seja a mesma, cada consulta executada acrescenta algum processamento, portanto se fizermos uma diferença entre processamento e dados transmitidos bruto e líquido, o bruto será bem maior do que no caso da leitura em blocos.
- **Conclusão**: viável apenas se a quantidade de itens consultados for pequena.

## Leitura Única com Tabela Auxiliar

Se de alguma forma os dados vem do banco de dados, seria mais fácil fazer um `JOIN` entre as tabelas ou mesmo usar o `IN` seguido de um `SELECT`. Exemplo:

```sql
select * from tab1 where tab1.id in (select tab1_id from tab2)
```

Caso os dados não estejam no banco de dados ainda seria possível incluí-los, por exemplo, numa tabela temporária.

- **Vantagem:** lê os dados necessário de uma só vez.
- **Desvantagem**: pode precisar incluir os dados no banco antes de consultar.
- **Conclusão**: mais adequando se os itens consultados estão de alguma forma disponíveis no banco de dados. Caso contrário, seria interessante fazer uma comparação para saber se o tempo adicional para inserir os itens em uma tabela temporária é maior ou menor do que o tempo adicional para consultar os registros em blocos usando `IN` com vários parâmetros.

## Leitura Única da Tabela Inteira

Leia toda a tabela e filtre os registros no Java.

- **Vantagem:** uma única consulta no banco.
- **Desvantagem**: precisa de várias consultas (qtd. itens / tamanho do bloco)
- **Conclusão**: interessante se a quantidade de registros total da tabela não for muito grande e também se não forem lidos muitos dados de cada registro, por exemplo se o caso for de uma leitura apenas do `id` de 2000 de um total de 4000 registros.

## Bônus

Se o desempenho for algo crítico, um *cache* em memória com os registros indexados em alguma estrutura de dados de fácil recuperação (mapa, conjunto, lista) pode ser algo a se pensar.

Comment: eu estou seguindo a leitura em blocos, pois realmente imaginei ser a mais viável nesse caso, pois nesse caso não seria adequado utilizar uma tabela auxiliar. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @WyllianNeo Se você vai gerar várias cláusulas `IN` para usar no WHERE de cada consulta (método "em bloco"), você pode também informar todas estas cláusulas IN no WHERE de **uma única query** separando-os por **OR**: `SELECT...WHERE CAMPO IN (VALOR 1, VALOR 2,...VALOR 2100) OR CAMPO IN (VALOR 2100, VALOR 2101,...VALOR 4200) OR CAMPO IN (...`.

Comment: @Caffé É uma boa ideia.

Comment: @Caffé realmente, uma boa sugestão, só não vou utilizar pois já realizei a outra e a alteração na estrutura do meu código demandaria um tempo que pelo menos no momento não tenho, mas numa próxima situação utilizarei para ver o funcionamento. Obrigado.

Comment: @WyllianNeo Por nada. Antes de migrar para esta sugestão, faça umas medições de performance para observar o ganho. Usando OR..IN em vez de várias queries demorará no mínimo o mesmo tempo e muito provavelmente será bem mais rápido.

Answer (score 0):

Isso me parece um caso de execução em bloco. Muitas vezes temos de processar muitos registros em uma rotina e diversos desenvolvedores reutilizam a camada de negócios (java ou c#) para isso, mas, a experiência mostra que você vai acabar compensando em hardware a implementação ou sofrendo para otimizar código e banco tentando ganhar milisegundos alterando pequenos trechos de código, quando, na verdade, boa parte do tempo gasto na rotina é gasto no tráfego de rede, abertura de conexões e gerenciamento da execução do lote.

A solução definitiva pra isso não existe, vai depender muito da sua visão longo prazo do sistema e do tamanho dos registros e ações de processamento que você realiza, bem como da arquitetura do seu sistema.

Se você não quer furar as camadas e quer realmente garantir que as regras de negócio estão sempre na codificação (c#, java,c++ etc) então, você vai penar um pouco para ganhar performance.

Uma alternativa simples, é reavaliar se você realmente precisa passar a lista de parametros que é resultado do filtro, quando pode simplesmente passar o filtro e operar o select no banco.

Uma vantagem nisso é que você usará apenas poucos parametros circulando pela rede (mais rápido) e como não terá que quebrar a lista, irá apenas uma vez no banco.

Uma outra alternativa é serializar em uma string e passar os parametros que você precisa, a meu ver, se você seleciona esses dados e um filtro, pode passar os valores do filtro para uma procedure é mais rápido e mais fácil.

Inclusive, se você realiza um processamento em lote com os dados que são passados (os muitos registros) você poderia realizar isso na procedure que recebe os parametros ou criar ma forma de agendamento com base nos filtros para processar os registros em um job.

Evitando travar a tela do usuário esperando respostas da transação.